# Error while building app in Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, apple-watch, xcode7.1beta

Currently I am trying to build our project in Xcode 7.1 and encountered an issue: "iOS xibs do not support target device type watch". I have tried removing the xib files and I got another error saying the xib does not exist. The project itself supports apple watch.

I have tried building from the same code in Xcode 6.4 and no issue given by it.

Appreciate all of your help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have accidentally included the XIB in your WatchKit extension or WatchApp extension.  (I know because it happened to me too)

To solve:

- In the Project navigator, click on the XIB file.
- Then, in the Utilities pane, look under 'Target Membership' and un-tick any
  'WatchKit Apps' or 'WatchKit Extensions'.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for replying. Will look into it once I got my hand on the macbook.